# getting new project template in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, project, new-operator

can someone help me in getting a New Project template by name "Domain-Specific Language" in Visual Studio 2010 as shown in the image: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC391586.png

googled a lot without finding the correct way....

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126593.aspx

Comment: i am not trying to Create a Domain-Specific Language Solution, but to install its template.... could you tell me how that is done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Visual Studio SDK

How to: Create a Domain-Specific Language Solution

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126593.aspx

Comment: could you tell me where i can download and install the template

Comment: If you install the SDK, the template comes with it, there is no seperate install

Comment: i installed the VS SDK, and ya it added two new templates, but not the one i specified.